# How to find mod of large numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to find `(a^(b^c)) % (10^9 + 7)` in Python for large inputs?
My code just get terminated after a few test cases.

**My code:**

```
numbers = list(map(int, input().split())) 
x = numbers[2] 
y = numbers[1] 
z = numbers[0] 
m = pow(10,9) + 7
a = pow(y,x) 
r = z % m 
for i in range (0,a): 
    r = r*z 
    r = r % m 
    print(r)
```

Comment: What is your current attempt right now?

Comment: numbers = list(map(int, input().split()))
x = numbers[2]
y = numbers[1]
z = numbers[0]
m = pow(10,9) + 7
a = pow(y,x)
r = z % m
for i in range (0,a):
    r = r*z
    r = r % m
print (r)

Comment: its very popular question but still the test cases gets timed out of my reference question

Comment: page not working : Hackerrank

Comment: u can refer image too

Answer (score 1):

You should use Fermat's Little Theorem and Pingala's algorithm for power.
`a ^ (p - 1)` is `1` so if you take `(b ^ c) % (10 ^ 9 + 6)` that will become 1 (after taking power of a) and for calculating power modulo a number you can use binary approach that is `a^2k % M = ((a^k % M)^2) % M` and `a ^ (2k + 1) % M = ((a % M) * (a^k % M) ^ 2) % M`.

```
f a b c p = modPow a (modPow b c (p - 1)) p

modPow x n p
    | n == 0 = 1
    | even n =
        let val = x ^ (n `div` 2)
        in (val * val) `mod` p
    | otherwise = (x * modPow x (n-1) p) `mod` p
```

Comment: i had tried that but doesn't work very well you can see the referred question

Comment: Note that modular exponentiation is built in to Python (3-argument `pow()`), so all this is just `pow(a, pow(b, c, p-1), p)` in Python.